# Magento2 i18n not working Magento_Ui custom theme

Tags: magento2, i18n

I tried to add a translation on :

```
app/design/frontend/Theme/theme/Magento_Ui/web/templates/form/field.html
```

I added a translation like this :

```
<div class="gotcompany" data-bind="i18n: 'Got a company'"></div>
```

My i18n file is here :

```
app/design/frontend/Theme/theme/i18n/fr_FR.csv
```

The translation does not work with 'Got a company', if I use 'Sign In' it works, I tried to change the text of Sign In to be where the translation come from, it works too

Configuration :

```
"Got a company","test entreprise",module,Magento_Customer
"Sign In","Se connecter",module,Magento_Customer
```

I also tried Magento_Ui for reference with no success

Need your help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that finally this is a problem of Magento core (Thanks of Tu Van who helped me),
you can force the translation by declaring mage/translate

```
define(['jquery','mage/translate'], function($){
```

and then calling the translations, also in the js file

```
$.mage.__('Got a company')
```

Answer (score 0):

Translation loading order by highest priority is:

1. Database (saved in translation table)
2. Themes (app/design/i18n folder)
3. Language packages (app/i18n/[Vendor_Name]/xx_yy folder)
4. Module (app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/i18n folder)

You are using translate by theme which can be overridden by Database. So, let's check if you or someone translated that string by Translate Inline Tool or not with the SQL query below:

```
SELECT * FROM translation WHERE `string` LIKE '%Got a company%';
```

If you found any result, let's remove that record.

Comment: templates can't be replaced by template, the folder name in module_ui is templates, there is also a template folder I tried also your two solutions, it doesn't work

Comment: Can you see class `gotcompany` when inspecting elements ?

Comment: Do you mean you've tried this in your html file and the translation work? `<div class="gotcompany" data-bind="i18n: 'Sign In'"></div>`

Comment: Yes I can see Class gotcompany, it show in inspector
<div class="gotcompany" data-bind="i18n: 'Sign In'">Se connecter</div>
but with 'Got a company' magento giving me <div class="gotcompany" data-bind="i18n: 'Got a company'">Got a company</div>

Comment: I also Tried "Got a company","test entreprise"  without module reference, but it's not working too.. I do not understand why

Comment: I've updated the solution in my answer, please give it a try. If your issue still persists, please let me know and check the notification frequently, I'll continue help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: 1> nothing in DB 
2> already tried with your old post solutions don't works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140153/discussion-between-tu-van-and-kevin-ami).